# Are lattice-based Monte Carlo simulations used in the case of liquids and gases?

Tags: monte-carlo, model-hamiltonians, atomistic-simulation, 2d-lattice, ising-model

The Ising model uses a lattice-based model as it is reasonable to simulate magnetic behavior in a solid.

Is lattice-based Monte Carlo modeling used in the case of the simulation of gases and liquids (i.e., pure liquids, not crystalline liquids)? If yes, when?

Comment: Are you asking about lattice-based simulations in general (including CFD methods, for example), or in particular about Monte Carlo simulations (as implied by the tags)?

Comment: @Anyon, Monte Carlo.

Comment: Clearly "yes" and "often": https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=lattice+monte+carlo+simulations+of+liquids+and+gases what _specifically_ do you want to know about lattice MC fluid simulations? This could be the topic of multiple reviews or even books.